# iMovie Help: Transition still keeps the previous clips' audio

Tags: audio

See where the cursor/line is? One of the cast members are still talking -- in the middle of a transition, how is that possible? Considering we see it END right before it fades to black? I have made it to fade out to black but still nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, a transition will start before the end of a clip.  You need enough video to have something to play while the transition is occurring.  The video will normally keep running until the end of the transition and that also means that the audio will keep running until the transition finishes.  You would need to play with the volume adjustments to bring down the level of the track that you don't want to have keep playing.

Answer (score 0):

The transition seems to catch audio from the next video. What worked for me was to detach the audio from that next clip and then play the segment.